# boolean flag is always false

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to interact with an API and see whether the user exists on that API by checking the JSON Response by comparing current email (stored in SharedPrefs) with the emails returned from API. If the user exist, a flag is set **true** so that the app doesn't send a POST request to save the new user and if it is **false**, the user gets saved in API.

So, this is the **UEC (UserExistenceChecker) class**

```
public class UEC extends AppCompatActivity {

List<SavePlace> userInfo;

String name;
boolean flag;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;

public UEC(SharedPreferences sharedPref){
    this.sharedPref = sharedPref;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public boolean checkIfUserExists() {

    email = sharedPref.getString("userEmail", "");

    Retrofit retrofitCheckUser = ApiClientSavePlace.getClient();
    ApiInterfaceSavePlace apiInterfaceSavePlace = retrofitCheckUser.create(ApiInterfaceSavePlace.class);
    final Call<List<SavePlace>> checkUser = apiInterfaceSavePlace.getSavePlaces();

    checkUser.enqueue(new Callback<List<SavePlace>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<SavePlace>> call, Response<List<SavePlace>> response) {
            userInfo = response.body();
            try {
                if(userInfo.size()!=0){
                    for (int i = 0; i <= userInfo.size(); i++) {
                        String emailReturned = userInfo.get(i).getEmail();
                        Log.d("response", "email returned: " + emailReturned);
                        Log.d("sharedpref", "email: " + email);
                        if (emailReturned.equals(email)) {
                        Log.d("response:", "email match?: " + emailReturned.equals(email));
                            flag = true;
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                            editor.putInt("userID", userInfo.get(i).getId());
                            Log.d("ID returned", String.valueOf(userInfo.get(i).getId()));
                            editor.apply();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SavePlace>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", "FAILED CHECKING USER ID/SOMETHING HAPPENED");
        }
    });
    return flag;
}

}
```

In this class, I have made a **boolean flag** with default value **false**

and this is how I call the method **checkIfUserExists()** from **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity{

SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    UEC uec = new UEC(sharedPref);
    boolean userExists = uec.checkIfUserExists();
    if (userExists) {
        Log.d("USERSTATUS", String.valueOf(sharedPref.getInt("userID", 0)));
    } else {
        Log.d("USERSTATUS", "FALSE:DOESNT EXIST");
        Log.d("USERSTATUS", String.valueOf(sharedPref.getInt("userID", 0)));
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that, according to the logs, **else** condition is always **true** because the **flag** is always **false** even though I am setting it **true** in **checkIfUserExists()** method.

and the interesting thing about **logs** is that this

```
05-13 15:27:54.278 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/USERSTATUS: FALSE:DOESNT 
EXIST
05-13 15:27:54.278 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/USERSTATUS: 12
```

comes first and then this comes in logs after above log

```
05-13 15:27:55.746 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/response: email 
returned: some-email@gmail.com
05-13 15:27:55.749 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/sharedpref: email: 
some-email@gmail.com
05-13 15:27:55.749 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/response: email 
returned: some-email@gmail.com
05-13 15:27:55.749 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/sharedpref: email: 
some-email@gmail.com
05-13 15:27:55.749 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/response: email match?: 
true
05-13 15:27:55.749 1613-1613/xyz.gautamhans.locus D/ID returned: 12
```

which means that it detected the email and set the sharedpref
but the flag is still false.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at your code it looks like that the enqueue method is causing for the boolean to only be changed to true after you call the `checkIfUserExists()` method.

This is what you're seeing in your logs, due to the asynchronous nature of the enqueue method, all the code within your `onResponse()` and `onFailure()` is only executed after everything else in a background thread.

To help avoid this you could implement a callback method so that whenever the `onResponse()` method is finished you call the method to check if the user exists. In the code below the callback method is `onUserExists()` which replaces the true boolean flag and I've also included an else statement if the user doesn't exist which will trigger a second callback, the `onUserDoesNotExist()` method. These callback methods will trigger the code in the MainActivity within the `onUserExists()` and `onUserDoesNotExist()` methods there.

```
public void checkIfUserExists(OnUserExistsCallback onUserExistsCallback) {

    email = sharedPref.getString("userEmail", "");

    Retrofit retrofitCheckUser = ApiClientSavePlace.getClient();
    ApiInterfaceSavePlace apiInterfaceSavePlace = retrofitCheckUser.create(ApiInterfaceSavePlace.class);
    final Call<List<SavePlace>> checkUser = apiInterfaceSavePlace.getSavePlaces();
    OnUserExistsCallback callback = onUserExistsCallback;
    checkUser.enqueue(new Callback<List<SavePlace>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<SavePlace>> call, Response<List<SavePlace>> response) {
            userInfo = response.body();
            try {
                if(userInfo.size()!=0){
                    for (int i = 0; i <= userInfo.size(); i++) {
                        String emailReturned = userInfo.get(i).getEmail();
                        Log.d("response", "email returned: " + emailReturned);
                        Log.d("sharedpref", "email: " + email);
                        if (emailReturned.equals(email)) {
                        Log.d("response:", "email match?: " + emailReturned.equals(email));
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                            editor.putInt("userID", userInfo.get(i).getId());
                            Log.d("ID returned", String.valueOf(userInfo.get(i).getId()));
                            editor.apply();
                            callback.onUserExists();
                            break;
                        } else {
                            callback.onUserDoesNotExist();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SavePlace>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", "FAILED CHECKING USER ID/SOMETHING HAPPENED");
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

For this to work you need to create the OnUserExistsCallback interface.

```
public interface OnUserExistsCallback {
     void onUserExists();

     void onUserDoesNotExist();
}
```

Finally this is how your MainActivity would now look.

```
public class MainActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    UEC uec = new UEC(sharedPref);
    uec.checkIfUserExists(new OnUserExistsCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserExists() {
                Log.d("USERSTATUS", String.valueOf(sharedPref.getInt("userID", 0)));
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserDoesNotExist() {
                Log.d("USERSTATUS", "FALSE:DOESNT EXIST");
                Log.d("USERSTATUS", String.valueOf(sharedPref.getInt("userID", 0)));
            }

        );
    }
```

Not sure if this will compile and run successfully as I haven't ran this code myself. Hopefully it will and that it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello. thank you for the answer. 
I am having trouble implementing your solution.

see this screenshot :

http://i.imgur.com/Rp7IPr4.png

Comment: @mnmncp first `onUserExistsCallback` should be capital 'O' not lower case 'o'.

Comment: your interface name also has lower case 'o' in the beginning

Comment: @mnmncp `public void checkIfUserExists(OnUserExistsCallback onUserExistsCallback)` you haven't included the parameter needed

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake.
So, I have implemented the solution but getting this in the logs:
https://hastebin.com/ulokigikog.scala

Comment: and one more thing, did you deliberately remove flag=true; statement in the code or it was done by an accident?

Comment: @mnmncp so it looks like my solution was checking if the user existed before it was even added to your SharedPreferences, I've updated the code so that the callback is executed after you apply your changes to your sharedPreferences. You no longer need the flag because you're using a callback instead.

Comment: ah, makes sense. 
take a look at this
https://hastebin.com/kunafanolu.scala

Comment: @mnmncp I'm not sure what you're wanting me to look at. Try and debug your app using the debugger: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is due to Asynchronous execution of `checkUser.enqueue(new Callback<List<SavePlace>>()`. So when you call this this method from `checkIfUserExists()`, your execution thread will not wait for `checkUser.enqueue()` to complete. Instead it will immediately go to the next line and return the current flag value which is false. `checkUser.enqueue()` will be executed in a background thread and you get the result in `onResponse()` method. The behaviour is correct as per your code. Please try to handle the scenarios asynchronously as that is the recommended approach for a Network call.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. Thank you.
Is there a possible solution to this problem that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem** is that you are dealing with asynchronous function call when you call this method

```
uec.checkIfUserExists();
```

the code inside this function is executed in normal way until the line where you make your api call here

```
final Call<List<SavePlace>> checkUser = apiInterfaceSavePlace.getSavePlaces();
```

which makes a web api call in background thread and your function executes in normal way and returns which means you will get flag as false value.
and when the background task is finished then the code inside

```
public void onResponse()
```

method is executed which is a callback method and you get your values with true flag.

**Solution**

You should wait for your api call to complete and then perform any check on user exist or not.
So one simple way is to put your user exist check inside onResponse() callback method itself.

And if you want to handle it in your activity or fragment you can create your own callback method and pass it to `checkIfUserExists();`

Something like this

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public void onCallback(boolean isUserExists);
}
```

and in your activity

```
uec.checkIfUserExists(
    new MyInterface(){
        @Override
        public void onCallback(boolean isUserExists){
            if (isUserExists) {
                //your code
            }
            else{
                //your code
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Make changes to you checkIfUserExists() method like this

```
public void checkIfUserExists(final MyInterface myInterface) {
    //your code
    checkUser.enqueue(new Callback<List<SavePlace>>(final MyInterface myInterface) {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<SavePlace>> call, Response<List<SavePlace>> response) {
            userInfo = response.body();
            try {
               //your code
                    if (emailReturned.equals(email)) {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    //pass your flag to callback method here.
                    myInterface.onCallback(flag);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<SavePlace>> call, Throwable throwable) {
          //Handle failure
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response.
Could you tell me how should I use the interface to call onCallBack method in checkIfUserExists() or enqueue method?